# Concat optaplanner constraint streams

Tags: java, optaplanner

Is it possible to concatenate two constraint streams of the same cardinality and with the same types?

For instance, I have a constraint stream containing all planned teams:

```
BiConstraintStream <Team, Long> plannedTeams(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Team.class)
        .ifExists(Planning.class, Joiners.equal(team -> team, Planning::getTeam))
        .groupBy(team -> team, Team::getCountPeople)
}
```

and a stream containing all non planned teams.

```
BiConstraintStream <Team, Long> nonPlannedTeams(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Team.class)
        .ifNotExists(Planning.class, Joiners.equal(team -> team, Planning::getTeam))
        .groupBy(team -> team, team -> team.getCountPeople()/2)
}
```

Now I want to set a constraint on the total count, by summing the count of both planned teams and unplanned teams, e.g.,

```
Constraint constraintOnCount(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return plannedTeams(constraintFactory).concat(nonPlannedTeams(constraintFactory))
        .groupBy(sum((team, count)->count))
        .filter(count -> count > 5)
        .penalize("too many people", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD, count -> count - 5)

}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Interesting proposal to enhance the CS API. We'll have to think about it.

Comment: This definitely isn't possible at the moment, but it is definitely interesting to consider. In the meantime, I'd try adding a shadow variable on `Team` which tells you if there is or is not a plan for that team - this way, you can achieve your goal with a single constraint, I think.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand your suggestion.
Do you propose to keep a reference to the Planning of a team in the Team class?

In a real world (where a team could be planned on multiple days, in multiple buildings, for example), this would introduce a complex datastructure, I fear.

Comment: See https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#shadowVariable . It is possible that this would require introduction of some new data structures in your domain, but in the absence of stream concat, it could be an acceptable solution.

Comment: @Bram Did you ever figure out how using a shadow variable would achieve the goal you wanted to get with concatenation? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork) Solver 1.3.0, there is now a way to concat streams. It's called `concat` and it is available on all cardinalities of constraint streams.